# MathOverflow has become StackExchange's main attraction?

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

It appears MathOverflow has become an art, a culture, and recreation, all at once!

[image]

While I would never dare to argue that some serious math cannot be classified as recreation, this might be a bit of an overstatement that needs correcting.

Comment: I noticed this, too. The link is also wrong.

Comment: MathOverflow is v1, right?

Comment: @Undo Was. It became a SE 2.0 site today.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I, for one, welcome our new MathOverlords.

Comment: What's going to happen to Mathematics SE?

Comment: My guess is that it'll continue to get 300-some questions a day.

Comment: The two won't be merged?

Comment: No. They have somewhat different audiences (there is overlap, but of course you can have accounts on both sites and participate as you wish).

Comment: The StackOverlords won't be pleased to hear this.

Comment: @Eric Shog9 will be fired shortly as punishment for this calculated treason.

Comment: That's ok; I've been promised a nice big slice of pi

Comment: Math puns are so square, Shog3.

Comment: This one's round...ish.

Comment: Call the pentagon!

Comment: interesting angle people are taking on this issue.  Math puns are integral to well being, particularly if they are in a sequence.

Comment: @Damien I feel that you're in your prime for math puns.

Comment: @MarkGarcia the puns here are but a fraction of the total volume I know.  My capacity for puns is infinite!

Comment: @Damien So pun-making is your area of specialization. Wonderful '`cos` I'm in for pun-making too! This has been `tan`tamount to competition `sin`ce you've started it!

Comment: @Damien BTW, why don't we set an agreement. Our paths have intersected at this moment and I feel that our union would be very beneficial to the art of punning.

Comment: @MarkGarcia there should be an SE for puns, it'd be integral to SE as a whole.

Comment: @Damien Then we are in good terms. :)

Answer (score 18):

Could I request (as a MathOverflow moderator) that we drop down one position on the 'Science' list, to appear after the 'basic' mathematics site?

Comment: You may get a bit more notice if you post this as it's own question.

Comment: I have this on my list now.